# Unrecognised user cancelling recurring subscription repeatedly

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I believe you cannot trigger a `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` with a `auto_renew_status` of false multiple times in a row? According to the documentation if I understood correctly, `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` receipts are triggered when a user indicates that they wish to stop their subscription under the subscriptions page in the app store itself. When a user presses the cancel subscription button, a `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` with a `auto_renew_status` of false will be sent to me from Apple. The next time the user visits that page on the app store again, the only option they will have is to re-activate their subscription through 1 of our provided subscription plans and choosing any of those plans would then trigger a `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` with a `auto_renew_status` of true.

I have received 4 `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` with a `auto_renew_status` of false 4 times so far from the same unrecognised `original_transaction_id`. That does not sound possible according to my understanding.

Comment: Are you acknowledging the request with a 200 response? If not they could be retrying the event thinking it failed.

Comment: As far as i know, I do not even need to respond with anything on my end to their cancellation request as its all done through the Apple app store which Apple would then update on the receipt data which is what most people generally tend to suggest. Polling the receipt data. The cancellation is between the user and Apple if i am not wrong thus the confusion as to how he could do it and yes, I am responding with 200 response as the other users are renewing and subscribing and cancelling as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use server-to-server notifications from Apple in our subscriptions manage service. I can tell that `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` works as expected for us. When user cancels subscription, we have `auto_renew_status` as `false`, and `true` when he enables it back.

I believe you are missing something. BTW why you need those notifications? They are almost useless.

This [article](https://blog.apphud.com/subscriptions-notifications/) may help you to understand how notifications work. Hope you find an issue in you code. You can also write us in online chat.

Comment: Your understanding of server-to-server notifications in your comment is the same as mine which would mean that a user cannot trigger a false followed by a false. It has to be false -> true -> false. What i have received from this particular user is 4 false in a row. Putting aside my code completely and just looking at the notifications that Apple has sent me. How would receiving 4 false in a row be possible?

Comment: @JoelHong are you responding with http 200? You can send these 4 notifications to our online chat, we will take a look. Maybe these notifications are duplicates?
Anyway, you shouldn't rely on `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS ` notification fields. There's a receipt data, you should better use it and validate receipt.

Comment: Because his a unrecognised user, I am unable to update his data on my end. But the question is more towards the relation between the user and Apple. Why is the app store allowing that user to cancel 4x in a row without first re-activating before a cancel. The bigger problem I suppose is that I cant seem to find out who this user is based on only his receipt data only as the original_transaction_id i acquired from polling his receipt does not belong to anyone in my database.

Comment: @JoelHong I believe Apple is re-sending request because you are not responding with http 200.

Comment: Ahh you were right. Such a silly mistake. At least now you have helped me solved repeated notifications from Apple. Might i ask if using original_transaction_id is a fullproof method of tracking a user?